# show NSDate calculations from UITextfield in UITableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield, nsdate

I am new to swift, so any help or info on where to look would be appreciated.

I am working on a small app that will calculate dates, a user can select a date from a date picker with in a text field. Once a date is selected it will display the calculated results in a table. The table will have section names such as  " 7 days back " then a table view cell displaying the date minus 7 days.

The app loads with the current date displayed in the text field and the table displaying the correct calculated dates. How ever once I try to change the date using the date picker the table doesn't reload and display the calculations for the new date that was selected, the textfield does change and update to the selected date just not the table cells. I worked on this for some time still no luck, when I debug the code it seems as if my variable doesn't update to the new date which probably explain why my table cells aren't not updating.

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried reloading the UITableView on date selection?